# Cucumber BDD test for Image File Upload API using spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have a **POST** api "`/api/user/profileImage`" to upload image, developed with spring boot. I have to write Cucumber BDD test to validate the api, unfortunately I can't find much references for cucumber BDD Test Scenario for file upload operation. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you want to test for? Can you identify which scenarios / test cases you want to cover? Depending on your programming language I'm sure you can find examples of how to upload files.

Comment: I want to test file upload with desired file type and size. I tried with files from resource folder (classpath),  but no luck.

Comment: So is your question about how to use Cucumber, or how to upload files to an endpoint?

Comment: how to write Cucumber Test case for File Upload in Spring Boot

Comment: I'm suggesting to break up your problem into smaller parts. Cucumber is just an abstraction layer on top of your programming language. So either start by writing the scenarios you want to implement ("Can you identify which scenarios / test cases you want to cover?") and implement them in small steps. Or start with writing the code to upload the files, and add the abstraction on top.